# Как выйти из if-блока?

Tags: php

При выполнении большого количества проверок, образуется много условий `if-else`. Например:

```
if(условие) {
  // ...
} elseif(условие) {
  // ...
} else {
  // Всё хорошо, идем дальше
  if(условие) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // Всё хорошо, идем дальше
    // ...
  }
}
```

Можно ли это как-то сократить?

Например, если бы можно было выходить из блока `if`, можно было бы не писать `else`. Но вроде бы оператор `break` такого не позволяет.

Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: Можно выходить почти из любого места программы, я использую для такого случая [goto](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.goto.php) ! В метку вынес проверку переменной которая заполняется false в случаи ошибки и true удачи, вместо кучи return и блоков else.

Comment: Я думаю оператор goto не то чтобы устарел, но является признаком плохого тона)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вынесите ваш блок проверок в отдельную функцию и используйте `return`

Или поднимайте исключения

Comment: В чем смысл тратить ресурсы на инициализацию дополнительной функции для возврата результата существующей функции  ?) если не учитывать относительно масштабной обработки результата перед его возвратом с учетом повторений в нескольких местах (чего в вопросе не было)

Comment: @noname2019 в повышении читабельности кода. Потери производительности при вызове ничтожна по сравнению со сложностью поддержки этого спагетти-кода

Comment: В чем читабельность то ? в увеличении и усложнении кода ?

Comment: @noname2019 в структурировании и разделении программы на логические блоки

Comment: против функций возражений не имею, но исключения то тут каким боком, автор же не заявляет, что это проверки ошибок каких-либо.

Comment: @teran это мое предположение. Исходя из комментариев `//Всё хорошо, идем дальше`

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как отнесутся к этому адепты правильного кода на php, но можно использовать ... цикл:

```
foreach([1] as $_not_used) {
    if(условие) {
        ...
        if(условие) {
            break;
        }
        ....
    }
    if($a==4) { break; }
 }
```

Кроме того, если условия подходящие, возможно использование конструкции switch. А так же вложенных конструкций циклов и switch с указанием оператору `break` количества уровней вложенности, из которого выходить.

Comment: надо сразу тогда `foreach( условие ? [1] : [] as $_not_used)` :D

Comment: @teran Не, там else на первое же условие есть, его с циклом сложновато изобразить будет :)

Comment: `условие ? $a = [1], $b = [] : $a= []; $b=[1]`;` и потом `foreach($a ....); foreach($b ...)`

Comment: мб через `for` удобнее будет `for(;условие;)` с брейком в конце

Comment: `$res = условие ? true : false` ... `for(;$res;) ... for(;!$res;)`

Comment: @teran Ну это уже детали. Совсем компактно все равно не выходит :(